# setting process.env.tz stops working when changing from node v8 to v10

Tags: node.js, angular, timezone, upgrade

We have an angular app and are looking at upgrading the node version from 8.11.4 to 10.16.0. When we change the node version, the timezones get messed up and offset to the wrong timezone.

We have the *process.env.tz* set to utc time and have confirmed in the js files that the variable is set where it should be working. In node 8.11.4 when you run `console.log(new Date().getTimezoneOffset())` it returns `zero`. But when you run the same command with 10.16.0 it returns `420`. We have not changed anything besides the node version between the two versions.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue. We originally had the  `process.env.TZ` set to `UTC+0` and we solved it by changing the value to just `UTC`.